# Can I use my old home partition and just format the root partition when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, partitioning, 12.10

I installed Ubuntu's root on one partition and /home on another. Now if I format the root partition, install fresh Ubuntu, and mount the previous /home partition as /home, will it pick up all my previous files and folders?

Comment: No. Not unless you explicitely mount the home partition as `/home`. To do that, select the Manual Partitioning option, also known as Something else, and select the appropriate mount point for the home partition.

Comment: @mikewhatever why dont you put your answer below. if its correct you will recieve points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If won't be picked up, unless you explicitely mount the home partition as /home. To do that, select the Manual Partitioning option (also known as Something Else), and select the appropriate mount point for the home partition.