# New UbuntuGnome install doesn't pick up /home partition as 'home'

Tags: partitioning

It appears that I'm in the same situation as this user ([Can I use my old home partition and just format the root partition when installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204387/can-i-use-my-old-home-partition-and-just-format-the-root-partition-when-installi)). As I've not done anything else besides install UbuntuGnome (using the 'Delete current OS and install' option, I should go back, re-install UbuntuGnome and select the 'Something else' option?

I chose that option on my first attempt to install but I went back to 'Delete current os' when the installer showed that my /home partition would be formatted with the 'Something else'. Apparently I need to manipulate the 'Something else' to NOT format my /home partition? Is there anything else I need to be aware of?

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 a couple of years ago and my /home was recognized automatically, but I've slept since then and don't remember exactly what I did.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

So I went back and re-installed UbuntuGnome and found that selecting partitions brings up other options that I wasn't aware of the first time (or was too scared to try!).

My old desktop and browser bookmarks are right where I left them.

Thanks for looking.